# flutter error LNK1104: cannot open file on windows

Tags: flutter, windows

Run/Debug on windows:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\myproject\build\windows\runner\Debug\myproject.exe' [C:\myproject\build\windows\runner\myproject.vcxproj]
```

No such error before. Searched web and tried:

```
1. flutter clean, flutter pub get
2. restart windows, restart vsc
3. taskkill /f /im myproject.exe
   the executable was not found in task manager.
```

No antivirus software installed except the built-in Microsoft antivirus service.

> flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2861], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.4)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.6 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^1.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: added flutter doctor and pubspec.

Comment: You are using an older version of flutter and Visual Studio. Updating both wouldn't hurt.

Comment: trying flutter upgrade, but it will remove local svn changes. why flutter wants to do that for upgrade? thanks.

Comment: This shouldn't occur. Did you modify the flutter installation? This could be the reason for this issue

Comment: I did not check out flutter source code and no changes to installation. After upgrading, the issue is gone. thanks a lot.